# How can you auto-increment a non primary ID column scoped to another table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's imagine that we're building GitHub and we have two tables: `repos` and `issues`. Every GitHub repo has a collection of issues, and so the `issues` table has a foreign key of `repo_id`.

Now, when you're browsing a GitHub repo's issues, you don't want to be exposed to the internal `id`. Instead, you want something like  a `number`, which increments from `1..n` for only that repository. You want your first issue in your new repo to be numbered `1`, not whatever the next `id` for an issue on GitHub is.

Of course, you need a way to increment, and you want to make sure that the `number` is unique when scoped to the repo. And so you especially want to avoid then any race condition where the same number can be generated twice.

What's the most straightforward way of handling this? A trigger? Something else entirely?

I am using PostgreSQL but would prefer approaches that are vanilla SQL where possible, e.g. triggers. If there's a simpler Postgres approach, then that would also be useful.

Any code that demonstrate your approach would be extraordinarily useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to do this without the possibility of a race condition. This should minimize race conditions but not eliminate them. There may be better ways within specific database architectures. Assuming "REPOSITORY_ID" is provided by your application code:

```
insert into issues (repo_id,line_id) values (
    REPOSITORY_ID,
    coalesce((select max(line_id)+1 from issues where repo_id=REPOSITORY_ID),0)
);
```

This pulls the current highest line_id and increments it at the time of the insert. If there are no records, it defaults to 0. There is a small chance of a race if two inserts hit at the exact same time, but it seems unlikely. If you enforce uniqueness you can check for an error on insert and retry on failure.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to add a new `issue` to a certain `repo`, you could execute the following operations:

1. start a new explicit transaction;
2. select the `repo` you want to modify with a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`. This will put a row-level lock on it and prevent other transactions that want to add a new `issue` for that `repo` to proceed concurrently;
3. get the new issue number for that `repo` in some way (for instance you could have a `latest_issue` column in `issue`, as in one of the answers, or you could perform a query to find it);
4. insert the new `issue` with the correct issue number;
5. terminate the transaction: this will release the lock and allow other transactions that want to work on the same `repo` to continue.

So you could define a stored procedure in this way, and call it every time you want to insert a new `issue`. Under the hypothesis that there are not too many concurrent transactions trying to insert new issues for the same repository, this would prevent race conditions and still operate with a reasonable efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep a `latest_issue` column in `repos` and initialize it to 0.
In `issues` I'd create a column `nr` with a `UNIQUE` constraint on `(repo_id, nr)`, where `repo_id` is the foreign key column in `issues`.

Whenever an issue is created, `latest_issue` in `repos` is increased. This number is then used as `nr` for `issues`.

Comment: Isn't it race vulnerable without locking?

Comment: No, just use `UPDATE ... RETURNING` to get the new issue number in a single transaction. That will do all the locking you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would tackle it:

```
create table repo(
  id serial primary key
);

create table issue(
  id integer not null,
  id_repo integer not null references repo(id),
  primary key (id, id_repo)
);

create function create_issue_seq() returns trigger as $$
  begin
    execute format('create sequence issue_%s_seq', new.id);
    return new;
  end
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger create_issue_seq after insert on repo
  for each row execute procedure create_issue_seq();

create function assign_issue_id() returns trigger as $$
  begin
    new.id = nextval(format('issue_%s_seq', new.id_repo));
    return new;
  end
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger assign_issue_id before insert on issue
  for each row execute procedure assign_issue_id();
```

One trigger creates issue id sequence after repo is created (dedicated for given repo) and second one utilizes existing dedicated sequence to properly fill issue id before issue is inserted.

Pros:

- race-free as it's using sequences in fact
- no exclusive locking needed

Cons:

- it creates a lot of sequences (although quick test with 1M repos shown it doesn't cause any serious performance loss)

Notes:

- probably it is wise to implement also some trigger which deletes sequence after delete on repo.
- I assumed immutable repo id (which I strongly believe it is the right way: to have immutable PK)